# Import/Export database from external MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am starting external MySQL server pragmatically by following way

StartMysqlServer.p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("server/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=server/my.ini --standalone --console --basedir=server/");

Now i want import/export for database present in this started MySQL through java code.i do not know is this possible or not? suggest any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the java Runtime to execute the same statements you would on the command line, so importing and exporting could be done in the same way:

Import

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "mysql -uusername -ppassword < /path/to/fileToImportFrom.sql");
```

Export

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "mysqldump -uusername -ppassword > /path/to/fileToExportTo.sql");
```

Alternatively you could connect to the database using the MySQL JDBC Driver and insert data programmatically. Using an API like Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) makes this less painful ([JdbcTemplate tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringJDBC/article.html)).

Comment: Thanks for reply but when i am using following code then process run for infinite time. the code is  Process runtimeProcess;
 
     runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -uroot -p > D:/fileToExportTo.sql");
     int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

     if (processComplete == 0) {
  System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
     } else {
  System.out.println("Could not created the backup");
     }

Comment: Because you are using `-p` but not providing the password, the process is waiting for you to provide your MySQL password. Try running the same command in your terminal to see what I mean.

Comment: As per suggestion i modified my code as below still it run for infinite time  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u root -p admin > D:/fileToExportTo.sql");

Comment: Thanks trf.I solved problem.Here is Link of blog that i referred  http://omindu.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/mysql-database-backup-restore-using-java/#comment-162

Comment: I have another query if i used MySQL Server present at path D:/Copies/10-10-2013/server - Copy (2)/bin> then how i run dump command on this path means i want import/export databases present in mentioned path Server.